# I need to detect touch of 2 autocad solids

Tags: c#, autocad

The only command that I can find close to what I need is the `fastselect` command. `FS` does not work with solids though.

Is there a way to know whether solids touch and do not interfere or intersect?

Comment: Do you mean the intersection? Have you tried intersect command?

Comment: intersect does not recognize object that do not overlap.

Comment: Improved some orthographics.

Answer (score 0):

Have you looked into using the AutoCAD BREP API to loop through Faces, Edges, and Shells?

It would give your the points/faces required that you could then interrogate to see if they're touching.